# Tag synonym proposal: analytics –> xDB

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Sitecore Analytics is a commonly used alias for the product that is nowadays called Sitecore xDB. As evidenced by the usage of [analytics](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytics), it is not seen by users as directly related to the Experience Analytics module or reporting in general.

I propose that we make [analytics](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analytics) to be a synonym of [xdb](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xdb).

If you agree or disagree, please go to the following page and vote the proposed synonyms up or down:

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/tags/xdb/synonyms

#### Related tags

Experience Analytics questions should be marked with [experience-analytics](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-analytics). It comes up as a suggestion when starting to type either "exp" and "ana".

[reporting](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reporting) is available as well for reporting-related questions.

Comment: I disagree with xDB but can't vote on the proposed synonym. DMS is a thing that exists out on the wild that is different than xDB. `dms` and `xdb` can stand up on their own.

Comment: @PeteNavarra How about `analytics`?

Comment: I tried to disagree with that one too, right up until I talked myself into it. =)

Comment: I can't vote on those either, but also disagree. DMS = sql based, xDB = mongo based, each of each bring about their own issues and reports. Analytics could equally apply to DMS and xDB so not sure it should be made a synonym either. Remember, what may be "common" to a 8.x customer may not be to a 7.2 customer.

Comment: @jammykam if something is specific to DMS or xDB, it should not be tagged as `analytics`. This tag is too ambiguous, so we should stop users from using it. I think the best thing to do would be to make it a synonym of `xdb` and then go over all questions (there aren't so many) and retag if necessary. That will result in a much smaller set of changes (and hence, bumped posts) than a manual retag without a synonym.